# Micronaut setter injection

Tags: java, micronaut

Micronaut is not injecting @Value on a setter method. Is it not supported? For example, I have

```
public class Example {


  @Value("${config.one}") //field injection works
  private String one;

  @Value("${config.two}") //field injection works
  private String two;

  @Value("${config.one}") //setter injection doesn't work
  public void setOne(String one) {
    this.one = one;
  }

  @Value("${config.two}") //setter injection doesn't work
  public void setTwo(String two) {
    this.two = two;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use setter injection, one has to use `@Inject` in conjunction with `@Property`.

```
  @Inject
  public void setOne(@Property(name = "config.one") String one) {
    this.one = one;
  }
```

There are some gotchas that one must be aware of. Just CTRL + F `Using the @Property Annotation` on [Micronaut Docs.](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

You class must be a bean of IoC container. The simplest way to get a bean is annotate class with `@javax.inject.Singleton`

You can check an example here https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#valueAnnotation

Comment: "You class must be a bean of IoC container. " - if it weren't already, then the field injection wouldn't be working.